# How to solve this unexpected use of comma operator?

Tags: reactjs

Just wondering how to resolve this, little new to react btw.

```
<button className="btn btn-light register-button" onClick={this.Subscribe, () => {sweetalertclick();}} 
                                type="submit" style={{ width: '50%' }} disabled={!allValid}>Subscribe</button>
```

Comment: Please provide more explicit description of the problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call `.Subscribe` and `sweetalertclick` separately.

```
onClick={(e) => {
  this.Subscribe(e); // if .Subscribe doesn't take an argument, you can omit the `e`
  sweetalertclick();
}}
```